Retina-Sized Images Trigger Lighthouse "Properly size images" Warning
My image dimensions are 264x270 when viewed on a "Moto G Power" viewport, which is what Lighthouse is currently using for its mobile audit.
I have a <picture> element set to deliver a 528x540 image on retina screens and a 264x270 image on non-retina screens.
<picture>
    <source 
        srcset="/assets/img/mypic_2x.webp 2x"
    />
    <img 
        src="/assets/img/mypic.webp" 
        alt="My Cool Picture" 
        width="264" 
        height="270"
    >
</picture>



But when I run a Lighthouse audit I get a "Properly size images" warning. If I remove the 2x source and just serve the 1x source the warning goes away. I thought Lighthouse was supposed to account for retina-sized images, why am I getting this error?

Did you happen to solve this?

@themartin Not yet. Based off of this Github issue I wonder if it wants us to reduce the file size rather than the dimensions. I would also recommend upvoting this FR for better explanation of what Lighthouse wants.
